# Jquery multiple select option uniqueness

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
var choices = [];
var previousChoice;
$(document)
    .on('focus',
        ".ddlConfidence",
        function() {
            // Store the current value on focus
            previousChoice = this.value;
        });
$(document)
    .on("change",
        ".ddlConfidence",
        function () {
            if ($(this).val() === "0") {
                //Remove from array
                choices.splice(choices.indexOf(parseInt(previousChoice)), 1);
    //TODO: Add choice back to all drop downs
            } else {
                //Add chosen to array
                choices.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
    //TODO: Remove choice from all drop downs except this one
            }
        });
```

Drop downs:

```
<select name="Picks[1].Confidence" class="form-control ddlConfidence">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="Picks[2].Confidence" class="form-control ddlConfidence">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I have 40 drop downs, each with 0-40 as options.  If a user selects a number greater than 0 I add it to an array, if they select 0 I remove it from the array.  How can I remove or add back the selected number from/to all dropdowns so that by the time they are done they would have had to select 1-40 uniquely for all drop downs (prevent them from selecting the same number twice by adding/removing it from all other drop downs.

Thanks!

Comment: Just as a note: `name` attributes with dots `.` are very bad practice

Comment: It's using C# MVC on the backend.

Comment: you can try to surround with a div with a related class or id: <div class="picks_1">... and then, you can reinsert using $('.picks_1').append('<div...><select.../></div>');

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but it works. When I need to add back in a choice, I add the option then re-order the option list:

```
var choices = [];
var previousChoice;

function Remove(choice) {
    choices.push(choice);
    $(".ddlConfidence")
        .each(function () {
            $(this).find("option[value=" + choice + "]option:not(:selected)").remove();
        });
}

function Add(choice) {
    choices.splice(choices.indexOf(choice), 1);
    $(".ddlConfidence")
        .each(function () {
            var sel = $(this);
            if (sel.find("option[value=" + choice + "]").val() === undefined) {
                sel.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", choice).text(choice));
            }
            var selected = sel.val();
            var opts_list = sel.find('option');
            opts_list.sort(function (a, b) { return parseInt($(a).val()) > parseInt($(b).val()) ? 1 : -1; });
            sel.html('').append(opts_list);
            sel.val(selected);
        });
}

$(document)
    .on('focus',
        ".ddlConfidence",
        function () {
            previousChoice = parseInt($(this).val());
        });
$(document)
    .on("change",
        ".ddlConfidence",
        function () {
            $(this).blur();
            var currentChoice = parseInt($(this).val());
            if (previousChoice > 0 && currentChoice > 0) {
                Remove(currentChoice);
                Add(previousChoice);
            } else if (currentChoice === 0) {
                Add(previousChoice);
            } else {
                Remove(currentChoice);
            }
        });
```